# Send GCM Notification from PHP

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send GCM notification using php. The script runs fine if I hard code the values and I do receive the notification as well. But when I try to pass the value as input, it fails with error:

```
{
  "multicast_id":8013504586085987118,
  "success":0,
  "failure":1,
  "canonical_ids":0,
  "results":[
    {
      "error":"InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}
```

Working Code:

```
<?php

// Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
$apiKey = "Google Api Key";

// Replace with the real client registration IDs


$registrationIDs = array("Registerationid");


// Message to be sent
//$message = "Your message e.g. the title of post";
$msg = array
(
'message'   => 'TestMessage',
'title'     => 'TestTitle',
'subtitle'  => 'TestSubtitle',
'tickerText'    => 'TestTicker',
'vibrate'   => 1,
'sound'     => 1,
'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);


// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array( "message" => $msg ),
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));
// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
//print_r($result);
//var_dump($result);
?>
```

code throwing error

```
<?php

$registrationIDs = array( $_GET['id'] );

// Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
$apiKey = "API KEY";

// Replace with the real client registration IDs


//$registrationIDs = array( $_GET['id'] );


// Message to be sent
//$message = "Your message e.g. the title of post";

$msg = array
(
'message'   => 'TestMessage',
'title'     => 'TestTitle',
'subtitle'  => 'TestSubtitle',
'tickerText'    => 'TestTicker',
'vibrate'   => 1,
'sound'     => 1,
'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);


// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array( "message" => $msg ),
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields));

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
// print the result if you really need to print else neglate thi
echo $result;
//print_r($result);
//var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your GET payload? `die(var_dump($_GET['id']));`

Comment: i am executing the php file directly from the browser with parameter http://localhost/notification3.php?id="Regid"

Comment: Don't use quotes around the ID. http://localhost/notification3.php?id=Regid

Comment: as i have declare the $_GET in an array , how can i pass multiple values. on passing values as a,b it fails